# Access value from tuple by key in python

Tags: python, hashmap

I have probability hash map in which key is probability value and value is their type. For obtaining highest probability i sorted the hash map but i can't figure out how to access the value with highest key value.

```
probability = {classify_email(mailmessage, android_term_df):"android" ,
                           classify_email(mailmessage, spam_term_df):"spam" ,
                           classify_email(mailmessage, c_term_df):"c" ,
                           classify_email(mailmessage, cplus_term_df):"cplus",
                           classify_email(mailmessage, java_term_df):"java",
                           classify_email(mailmessage, php_term_df):"php" ,
                           classify_email(mailmessage, easyham_term_df):"ham" 
                           }
            sorted_probability = sorted(probability.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: your hashmap is very strange. normally, the keys are the constants and the values are variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need to sort:

```
highest_probabilty_type = probability[max(probability.keys())]
```

Answer (score 0):

Should 2 of your classes have the exact same probability, only one of them would be retained in a dictionary in code like this.

What you should to do is to use the **classes as keys** and the **probability 
as value**.

```
from operator import itemgetter

dfs = {
    "android": android_term_df,
    "spam": spam_term_df,
    "c": c_term_df,
    "cplus": cplus_term_df,
    "java": java_term_df,
    "php": php_term_df,
    "ham": ham_term_df,
}

probabilities = { cls: classify_email(mailmessage, dfs[cls]) for cls in dfs }

# now they are classes -> probability
max_cls, max_prob = max(probabilities.items(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

Or, if you need the sorted list of distributions, put them into a list of `(probability, class)` tuples:

```
probabilities = [ (classify_email(mailmessage, dfs[cls], cls)) for cls in dfs ]
probabilities.sort()
```

Notice that with this, unlike your original example, you will not lose any pairs in case of duplicates.